# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 texture update shows black

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I'm trying to render a XML layout to an OpenGL surface. That works correctly, and I can do 3D effects on the layout. But, when I try to update it and render it again, it does not work. With twiddling and trying different functions, the end result is either a black object, graphic corruption on widgets external to the surface, or the original object without any modification.

My code to transform a view to a bitmap is:

```java
public static Bitmap toBitmap(final View view) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 100,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    final int width = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(),
            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    final int height = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(),
            MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    view.measure(width, height);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(view.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Then, in my object's constructor, I call:

```java
public static int loadTexture(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0) {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        bitmap.recycle();
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Calling the `loadTexture()` method again with an updated layout will render it black. I wrote another small method to try different ways:

```java
public static int updateTexture(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

    GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, bitmap);
    //GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    // GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

This leaves the original texture unchanged, and produces an error:

```java
<qgl2DrvAPI_glTexSubImage2D:502>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
glStartTilingQCOM: 0x501
```

Commenting the `texSubImage2D()` call and replacing it with `texImage2D()` does nothing, and produces no error message.

If anyone can shed light on anything I may have done wrong, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling the update method from the OpenGL thread? You don't need to specify again the texture parameters if you are using the texSubImage function.

Comment: @TraxNet That solved it: I now register that I want to update the texture, then in `onDraw()` I do the proper update. Now I'm stuck with my new texture leaking on other surfaces, but I believe this new bug is unrelated to this question.

Comment: I added an answer (copy&pasted my comment) so that you can mark it as solved. Open a new question with regarding your new problem. Best regards.

Comment: That texture leaking problem was me improperly sharing the texture handles between faces. A simple logic bug that was fixed by keeping that handle isolated.

Comment: Great you found it, keep on the hard work! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling the update method from the OpenGL thread? You don't need to specify again the texture parameters if you are using the texSubImage function.